# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value

Tags: android, xml, string

I'm trying to build android, and everthing was going smooth till i added LockScreenNotifications...

It gave me the following errors:

> packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:20:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'title' with value '@string/title_general').
>   packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:24:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'title' with value '@string/screen_security_category').
>   packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:24:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'summary' with value '@string/screen_security_summary').
>   packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:38:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'dialogTitle' with value '@string/lockscreen_battery_status_title').
>   packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:38:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'title' with value '@string/lockscreen_battery_status_title').
>   packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:38:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'entries' with value '@array/lockscreen_battery_status_entries').
>   packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:38:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'entryValues' with value '@array/lockscreen_battery_status_values').
>   packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:47:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'summary' with value
>   '@string/battery_around_lockscreen_ring_summary').
>   packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:55:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'title' with value '@string/title_shortcuts').
>   packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:65:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'title' with value '@string/lockscreen_buttons_title').
>   packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/lockscreen_interface_settings.xml:65:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'summary' with value '@string/lockscreen_buttons_summary').

When i open up the file it looks like this:

> ```
>  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
>  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
>  You may obtain a copy of the License at
>
>       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
>  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
>  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
>  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
>  limitations under the License.
> ```
>
> -->
>
> ```
> <PreferenceCategory
>     android:title="@string/title_general"
>     android:key="lockscreen_general_category" >
>
>     <PreferenceScreen
>         android:key="screen_security"
>         android:fragment="com.android.settings.SecuritySettings"
>         android:title="@string/screen_security_category"
>         android:summary="@string/screen_security_summary">                        
>     </PreferenceScreen>
> ```
>
> ```
>     <ListPreference
>         android:key="lockscreen_battery_status"
>         android:persistent="false"
>         android:dialogTitle="@string/lockscreen_battery_status_title"
>         android:title="@string/lockscreen_battery_status_title"
>         android:entries="@array/lockscreen_battery_status_entries"
>         android:entryValues="@array/lockscreen_battery_status_values"
>         android:defaultValue="0" />
>
>     <CheckBoxPreference
>         android:key="battery_around_lockscreen_ring"
>         android:title="@string/battery_around_lockscreen_ring"
>           android:summary="@string/battery_around_lockscreen_ring_summary"
>         android:defaultValue="true" />
>
> </PreferenceCategory>
>
> <PreferenceCategory
>     android:title="@string/title_shortcuts"
>     android:key="lockscreen_shortcuts_category" >
> ```
>
> ```
>     <PreferenceScreen
>         android:fragment="com.android.settings.mahdi.LockscreenButtons"
>         android:key="lockscreen_buttons"
>         android:title="@string/lockscreen_buttons_title"
>         android:summary="@string/lockscreen_buttons_summary" />
>
> </PreferenceCategory>
>    </PreferenceScreen>
> ```

can somebody tell me what i did wrong?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have any string defined at strings.xml, in your project, with that name?

Comment: How can I see if a string is defined?

Comment: Open your strings.xml file in res folder and check if the string is there. It probably isn't, since you don't know how to check it :D

Comment: Okay and can u give me an example of such a string? So that I know how to add it?

Comment: Of course. See here how to add it: https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicNetworking/res/values/strings.html.
An example would be `<string name="title_general">My general title</string>`

Comment: OK, then give some feedback on the result

Comment: I will when I get home...

Comment: thanks for the help it did help, altough i didn't need the lines that where added here, but do understand a lot more with the link and help u provited...

Comment: Right, so did you resolved your issue?

Comment: can u contact me trough hangouts?